# What does CC means in Soong?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, android-soong

There are a lot of references to cc in AOSP Soong. In this file, for example: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/master/cc/cc.go

I have several hypothesis:

1. Compiler Collection (as in gcc)
2. Cross Compiler
3. C, C++
4. C compiler ([as in cc so tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cc))

Answer (score 2):

It's your 4th hypothesis, "C compiler".

This is confirmed by the file you linked, which states at the top:

> This file contains the module types for compiling C/C++ for Android, and converts the properties into the flags and filenames necessary to pass to the compiler.

And the StackOverflow tag also states:

> cc is a common name for a C compiler executable or driver.

Furthermore, the file you linked is very clearly used for compiling C / C++, with hundreds if not thousands of references to the process.

I'm not 100% sure what you're after, since you seem to have managed to find the answer yourself!

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for confirmation. C Compiler is not that that evident for compiling C++.

Comment: A fair point! The languages are closely tied so compilers for both are quite common, at least common enough to earn the `cc` acronym. Glad I helped.